# Dynamically create column name postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I'm trying to create a function that will return a table of data.  The problem I'm running into is that I want some of the columns to be dynamically created based on what the year is in the `Date` column of the joining table.

For example, if a record's `date` field has a year of '2016', then I want '2016' to be concatenated with 'subdepartment_name_' to create the column name in the `SELECT` query.

Below is what I've written so far.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sample_function ()
RETURNS TABLE(subdepartment_name text,
              subdepartment_number text,
              department_number text,
              department_name text,
              my_column1 text,
              my_column2 text) AS
$$
DECLARE
    year TEXT;
BEGIN
  year := date_part('year'::text, table1.date);
  RETURN QUERY
    EXECUTE 'SELECT table2.subdepartment_number_'||year||
            ',table2.subdepartment_name_'||year||
            ',table2.department_number_'||year||
            ',table2.department_name_'||year||
            ',table1.*
            FROM
               table1
            LEFT JOIN
               table2
            ON
               table1.team = table2.team_number;';
END;
$$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

When running this function as `SELECT * FROM sample_function()` I get this error:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "table1"
LINE 1: SELECT date_part('year'::text, table1....
                                       ^
QUERY:  SELECT date_part('year'::text, table1.date)
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function sample_function() line 5 at assignment

********** Error **********

ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "table1"
SQL state: 42P01
Context: PL/pgSQL function sample_function() line 5 at assignment
```

Is there a simple way to do this that I'm missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Having the year as part of the column name is a bad idea. Read up on database normalization

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know, it wasn't my first choice, but our data is really wacky.  Hopefully we'll find a better way, but I'm just experimenting for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment

```
year := date_part('year'::text, table1.date);
```

is equivalent to

```
year := (select date_part('year'::text, table1.date));
```

As you can see there is no `table1` in `from` clause of the query (because of lack of `from` clause;). You should try:

```
year := date_part('year'::text, table1.date) from table1 limit 1;
-- or
year := date_part('year'::text, table1.date) from table1 where id = 1;
-- or something else, the query should return exactly one row
```

Simple assignment needs the query to yield exactly one row.
If you want to do something for a set of values use `loop`, e.g.:

```
for year in
    select distinct date_part('year', table1.date) from table1
loop
    -- do something with year
end loop;
```

Comment: Beautiful!  Thank you!  Also, do you know how to make this work if more than one year is present in table1?  Meaning that the date_part function could return more than 1 record if the "limit 1" argument wasn't used.